# Is there a way to get a non-squared ALAsset thumbnail?

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary

I've noticed when using the Apple's photos app - while scrolling fast (in non-grid mode) the photos appear in a lower quality and after some time they are replaced with a higher quality image. Obviously it is done due to Performance reasons.

Trying to mimic the photos app I used the `asset.thumbnail`, however the thumbnail provided is squared and `asset.defaultRepresetnation.fullScreenImage/fullResolution` takes a lot of time to load.

Any other way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes,  there is. Starting in ios 5 you can call the method `aspectRatioThumbnail` of `ALAsset` to accomplish this.